# Retrying connect to server: hadoopmaster/IP:9000

Tags: hadoop, host, ufw

I installed **Hadoop 2.9.0**.  I checked jps in slave nodes, are running `datanode` and `nodemanager` in slaves and `namenode` and `resourcemanager` in master. Please help that Why is this error? According to presented solutions, I disabled `firewall`, `SELinux` and `IPv6`. Problem is that `Live nodes` in web UI is 0.

**/etc/hosts**:

```
1       localhost
127.0.1.1       hadoopmaster

#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

192.168.111.154 hadoopmaster
192.168.111... hadoopslave1
192.168.111... hadoopslave2
192.168.111... hadoopslave3
```

Configuration in all of the nodes:

**core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
   <value>hadoopmaster:8025</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
   <value>hadoopmaster:8030</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
   <value>hadoopmaster:8050</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Output of `netstat -nap | grep 9000`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18205/java      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:59048         127.0.1.1:9000          TIME_WAIT   -
```

I restarted hadoop and formatted namenode again and agin But still I get this error: (hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoopslave1.log)

> 2018-06-11 02:42:33,593 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying
>   connect to server: hadoopmaster/192.168.111.154:9000. Already tried 4
>   time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000
>   MILLISECONDS)

Comment: you don't need to mention the port number in FS.defaultFS property. Just mention the FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain name) there. And make sure you have updated /etc/hosts file with all the master-slaves IP addresses and their respective FQDN. The value of FS.defaultFS must look like "hdfs://<machine_name>.<organisation_name>.com"

Comment: You should also remove the line with 127.0.1.1 address from all hosts... Otherwise, it's only listening on that local address, not the external one

Comment: @Abhinav, Are you sure that there is need to FQDN for FS.defaultFS?  Because I saw just is entered the hostname in configurations, no FQDN .

Comment: FQDN must be defined in /etc/hosts and yes there is no need to provide any port number in FS.defaultFS and also follow @cricket_007 instruction. What he said is also needs to be done

Comment: I did everything that you said, My problem solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. **edit /etc/hosts**

1. Define FQDN
2. Remove 127.0.1.1